# How do I update the hardware details for a system in Beaker?

Tags: beaker-testing

The hardware details shown in Beaker for my system are out of date, because the hardware has been modified. How can I update Beaker's records so that they reflect the current hardware?

Answer (score 0):

The inventory details for a system are gathered automatically using the [/distribution/inventory](https://beaker-project.org/docs/user-guide/beaker-provided-tasks.html#inventory-task) task. The easiest way to run this task is to use the [`bkr machine-test`](https://beaker-project.org/docs/man/bkr-machine-test.html) workflow command to generate and submit an appropriate job definition:

```
bkr machine-test --inventory --family=RedHatEnterpriseLinux6 \
                 --arch=x86_64 --machine=host1.example.com
```

This command will submit a job running /distribution/inventory on `host1.example.com` after provisioning RHEL6.

---

There is also a standalone command `beaker-system-scan` available in the Beaker harness yum repos. The `/distribution/inventory` task uses this command under the covers. You could install it and run it by hand on the system, if you want to update the system's hardware details in Beaker without reprovisioning it.